# CSS LESS - Nested sibling selector

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to get familiar with CSS LESS and I'm trying to get a `div` with the class `navbar-second` to move when an element with the class `navbar-wrapper` is hovered.

I've got this to work for the second element, but not for the first, and I've therefore been during a lot of weird things which you guys can see here:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper navbar-first">
    ...
</div>

<div class="navbar-wrapper navbar-second">
    ...
</div>
```

and the styling:

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    background: url(../../assets/images/MenuBackground.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);

    &:hover {
        &.navbar-second {
            transition: top ease .5s;
            top: 0px;
        }
    }

    ...
}

.navbar-first {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

    &:hover {
        &+&.navbar-second {
            transition: top ease .5s;
            top: 0px;
        }
    }

    ...
}

.navbar-second {
    position: relative;
    transition: top ease .5s;
    top: -50px;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just `+`, not `&+&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `+ .navbar-second` rather than `&+&.navbar-second`:

```
.navbar-first {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

    &:hover {
        + .navbar-second {
            transition: top ease .5s;
            top: 0px;
        }
    }
}
```

Which will compile to:

```
.navbar-first:hover + .navbar-second {}
```

Previously it was compiling to the following:

```
.navbar-first:hover + .navbar-first:hover.navbar-second {}
```

It's worth noting that `&` references the [parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature), which means that the selector `.navbar-first:hover` was being substituted for each `&`.